# istio on k8s gateway hosts value

Tags: yaml, minikube, istio

I am trying to follow the instructions at https://istio.io/docs/guides/bookinfo/ and https://istio.io/docs/tasks/traffic-management/ingress/#determining-the-ingress-ip-and-ports to put istio on the minikube.

The pod and service seems up and running fine.
[image]

Then I export port and host

> export INGRESS_PORT=$(kubectl -n istio-system get service istio-ingressgateway -o jsonpath='{.spec.ports[?(@.name=="http")].nodePort}')
>
> export SECURE_INGRESS_PORT=$(kubectl -n istio-system get service
> istio-ingressgateway -o
> jsonpath='{.spec.ports[?(@.name=="https")].nodePort}')
>
> export INGRESS_HOST=$(kubectl get po -l istio=ingressgateway -n istio-system -o 'jsonpath={.items[0].status.hostIP}')

From my understanding, the next step is to configure ingress with the istio gateway. In the below yaml, what's the hosts value should I put?

```
cat <<EOF | istioctl create -f -
apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1alpha3
kind: Gateway
metadata:
  name: book-gateway
spec:
  selector:
    istio: ingressgateway # use Istio default gateway implementation
  servers:
  - port:
      number: 80
      name: http
      protocol: HTTP
    hosts:
    - 
EOF
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You should specify `"*"`. Note step 3 in https://istio.io/docs/guides/bookinfo/#running-on-kubernetes

> Define the ingress gateway for the application

You have a prepared yaml file for that:  [samples/bookinfo/routing/bookinfo-gateway.yaml](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/istio/istio/release-0.8/samples/bookinfo/routing/bookinfo-gateway.yaml)

Troubleshooting ingress gateway:

```
$ istioctl get gateway bookinfo-gateway -o yaml
$ istioctl get virtualservice bookinfo -o yaml
$ kubectl get svc -n istio-system
$ kubectl logs -n istio-system -l istio=ingressgateway
```

Comment: I did step 3. That's how I get the all the pods running. (the blue screenshot above). did I miss anything?

Comment: So made some progress as the above second blue screenshot shows. Now I am getting 503. How to troubleshoot this error?

Comment: I have added some instructions for troubleshooting ingress gateway.

Comment: Do I need a cert file to make istio work? [2018-06-28 02:57:06.597][14][critical][main] external/envoy/source/server/server.cc:77] error initializing configuration '/etc/istio/proxy/envoy-rev0.json': unable to read file: /etc/certs/root-cert.pem
[2018-06-28 02:57:06.597][14][info][main] external/envoy/source/server/server.cc:435] exiting

Answer (score 0):

Even the sidecar is running, I have to use

> If you are using manual sidecar injection, use the following command
>
> $ kubectl apply -f <(istioctl kube-inject -f
>   samples/bookinfo/kube/bookinfo.yaml)

https://istio.io/docs/guides/bookinfo/

The below auto injection doesn't work.

> If you are using a cluster with automatic sidecar injection enabled,
>   simply deploy the services using kubectl
>
> $ kubectl apply -f samples/bookinfo/kube/bookinfo.yaml Copy

It's because the labels need to be provided for the auto injection.

> The Istio-Sidecar-injector will automatically inject Envoy containers
>   into your application pods assuming running in namespaces labeled with
>   istio-injection=enabled
>
> $ kubectl label namespace  istio-injection=enabled $
>   kubectl create -n  -f .yaml Copy

https://istio.io/docs/setup/kubernetes/quick-start/